# Multiple Objects vs Changing One Object

Tags: java, coding-style

I saw something today talking about this:

```
aClass something;
while (condition) {
    something = new aClass();
    ...
}
```

```
while (condition) {
    aClass something = new aClass();
    ...
}
```

It said you should use the second one rather than the first. Is this true, and if so, why?

Comment: Somebody should change the title of this question.

Comment: My apologies, my vocabulary is not very good.

Comment: That's okay, neither is mine, otherwise I'd rename it myself :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second method keeps the `something` variable only in the scope of that specific loop iteration.
If you want to use the object outside the loop and / or keep the changes saved between iterations then you must use the first method.

Also, the second method doesn't define multiple variables, the compiler will usually optimize it in a way that makes sure only one variable is defined.

Answer (score 4):

Your first example leaks a useless variable into the outer scope.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the second example *unless* you need to use the object after the while loop is complete.  If you don't need the variable in the outer scope it's better to declare it in the narrowest scope where it will be used (inside the loop).  This simplifies the code for maintenance programmers who have to make sense of it.

Comment: Could you please elaborate why?